# Python: Convert all files in directory into one .TXT?

Tags: python, text, docx

I have been trying to convert a number of DOCX files into TXT.

It works for a single file using the code below:

```
import docx    
def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename='/content/drive/My Drive/path/file.DOCX';  #file name
    fullText=getText(filename)
    print (fullText)

file = open("copy.txt", "w") 
file.write(fullText) 
file.close()
```

I tried different options (i.e. glob) but did not manage get it to do the above operation on all files in a folder.

Ideally the output should be 1 large text file and not separate ones.
I will need to do some formatting and assigning of IDs in that file in a next step.

Thank you for your help!
corp-alt

Answer (score 1):

With `file = open("copy.txt", "w")` you open the file and replace its content with `write()`.

With `file = open("copy.txt", "a")` you append to the existing file with `write()`. Or maybe even better:

With `file = open("copy.txt", "a+")` you append to an existing file with `write()`, or create a new file if it doesn't exist yet.

To go through all  files in a folder you can loop over them:

```
import os
import docx    

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foldername='/content/drive/My Drive/path/';  #folder name
    all_files = os.listdir(foldername) #get all filenames
    docx_files =  [ filename for filename in all_files if filename.endswith('.docx') ] #get  .docx filenames

    file = open("copy.txt", "a+") 
    for docx_file in docx_files: #loop over .docx files
       fullText=getText(filename)
       file.write(fullText) 

    file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Finn. That is already very helpful. The original files are all .DOCX files though and I need to convert them to .TXT (strip them of formatting) etc. 

Do you have an idea how to tell him to select all .DOCX files in the folder and apply the above code?

Comment: Thank you! I ran the updated solution and there is no error message. The created .txt file is empty though. Not sure why! When I tried my original code on a single DOCX it was successful. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Hmm. I think he did not find the docx files. Can you put the .py file in the same folder as the docx and change  `os.listdir(foldername)` to `os.listdir()`?

Comment: Apologies, I have been travelling for a few days. I am using Google Drive and Colab, maybe that causes the problem?

Comment: probably! the `os` part works like this only for files in your operation system (files in C: for example). Unfortunately i have never worked with colab